# What are the standard GUI elements called?

Tags: documentation

Is there a list of what the standard elements on an Android devices are called?

I can use everything just fine, but explaining to others to "use that bar at the top" and "the button that looks like a piece of paper" and so on is a) embarrassing and b) not the easiest way to explain things. Searching for names, I always end up at the GUI-documentation, which is useful in general, but certainly not in this case!

Comment: A place found thanks to the names provided: http://www.beginandroid.com/notifications.shtml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Top bar - **Notification bar**
Bottom bar - **Navigation bar**
Standard Navigation bar buttons - **Back**, **Home**, **Recent Apps**
These are the standard ones in every Android powered device.
*Note - The word "bar" can be replaced by "panel" sometimes.*

Update:  Title bar (which has app title, search button, back key) - **Action bar**

Comment: Thank you :). This helped AND put me on the path to some helpful sites. Amazing what you can find once you know the name of one or two things :).